# How to address the ability to work with culturally diverse populations and on interdisciplinary teams in an academic job application?

Tags: job, faculty-application, academic-life

Sometimes it is mentioned in the US academic position announcement that "Applicants must address in their application their ability to work with culturally diverse populations and on interdisciplinary teams" where the following documents are asked from the applicants:
1) resume, 
2) work-related references, 
3) letter of application, 
4) official employment application

I would like to know how to address one's ability to work with culturally diverse populations and on interdisciplinary teams in an efficient and effective way through these above-mentioned documents. No.3 (i.e cover letter, usually not more than 2-pages) could be the most probable one where the applicant may claim briefly that he or she has the ability ...... Is there anything else the candidates should be doing in this regard?

Comment: All such things generally go in the cover letter. Where else would you put them? Actually, at least you have something to include in the letter, I usually struggle to write one page of relevant stuff; you get a topic for 10 lines for free! ;-)

Comment: Take the free online class:  http://www.cirtl.net/f15-diversity-in-stem
I took a similar class.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, this can be addressed in (1) and (3) by specifically (re)writing portions of your resume and cover letter to highlight interdisciplinary work you've done and multicultural teams you've been a part of, and in (2) by asking your references to mention it in their conversations/letters.

More specifically:

While it's pretty obvious that most cover letters you send out will be at least somewhat specific to the each position, it may be less apparently that your resume can be the same. In this case, you'll want to modify your resume to highlight cross-disciplinary and multicultural work you've done at previous institutions. List bullet points that specifically call out researchers from other fields. Mention the nationalities of the colleagues with whom you've had a public collaboration. For both of these, it will look *waaay* better if you also list papers you've written or grants that were funded as a result of the collaboration; it will show that you can not only collaborate, but you can collaborate *effectively*.

For your references, you should mention that this position is something that the institution is asking to have called out, and request that they do so in their letters and conversations. This is as simple as it sounds; just speak to them and make sure they're aware of it. Hopefully they won't forget and all will be well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the "culturally diverse populations" part of your question, and hope that someone else addresses the "interdisciplinary teams" part.

When I sit on a committee evaluating candidates, I look very carefully at this aspect.  (Truth be told, not everyone does... but there are other people out there who share my interest in this aspect of hiring.)  When I see a candidate who is strong in other respects, I pore over the application packet to try to find evidence that the candidate "gets" it, and that the candidate will support the institution's commitment to increasing racial and cultural diversity.

I look in all four places.

I'm not saying you have to cover all four....  I'm saying that if candidates have relevant real-life experience and and a thoughtful attitude regarding the challenges faced in academia by members of underrepresented groups, they may very well have things to include in any or all of those four parts of the application.

In case you are also wondering **But what should I do if I don't have any experience working with culturally diverse populations?** I would say, in the short term, be honest.  In the long term, you might ask your institution's outreach department how you might support their efforts -- you could start with something as simple as showing people around your lab on an annual community visitation day.